# R: Using all.equal with more than two objects

Tags: r

When I compare more than two objects with `identical` the results make sense, but I do not understand what `all.equal` is doing. What is the logic behind the results that `all.equal` is outputting?

```
identical(25 + 2, 27)  #TRUE -- makes sense
identical(25, 2, 27)   #FALSE -- makes sense
identical(27, 22, 27)  #FALSE -- makes sense

all.equal(25 + 2, 27)  #TRUE -- makes sense
all.equal(25, 2, 27)   #TRUE -- why?
all.equal(27, 22, 27)  #TRUE -- why?
```

If either one of the last two `all.equal()` tests were false I would understand what R is doing -- either testing whether any sum of objects is equal (25+2==27) or testing whether any two objects are equal (27==27).

What is all.equal testing such that both of the last two equations are true?

Comment: I don't see any explanation there of the behavior of the last two lines of code in my question. I'm not looking for a way to compare multiple objects, I'm looking for an explanation of the `all.equal` output in my question

Comment: My guess is that the last item is getting treated as the tolerance. Note this from the help for all.equal: "Remember that arguments which follow ... must be specified by (unabbreviated) name: some of them were before ... prior to R 3.1.0. It is inadvisable to pass unnamed arguments in ... as these will match different arguments in different methods."

Comment: @Dason That looks like that's it! Considering the output from `all.equal(27, 27+27, tolerance = 27)  #TRUE` and `all.equal(27, 27+28, tolerance = 27)  #FALSE`

Comment: According to the help info, neither `identical` nor `all.equal` are supposed to compare more than two items.  In each case, the third argument is interpreted as something else.  For `all.equal` it is the tolerance, for `identical` it is a logical indicator to do with the comparison of double-precision or complex numbers.  It just happens to give a believable answer in your examples, but I wouldn't rely on it in general!  `identical(22,22,25)` is `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

The comments above appear to be correct. The arguments are taken in order, and the third argument is designated as the tolerance. However, the following results appear even stranger.

```
all.equal(target=25, current=2, 5) 
[1] TRUE
```

and

```
all.equal(target=25, current=2, tolerance=5) 
[1] TRUE
```

Here, the tolerance is clearly smaller than the difference, but TRUE is still returned. If we reduce tolerance to be even smaller, we get

```
all.equal(target=25, current=2, tolerance=.05) 
[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.92"
```

What is going on is that relative differences are calculated based on the mean value of the target argument. From the help file,

> Numerical comparisons for scale = NULL (the default) are typically on relative difference scale unless the target values are close to zero: First, the mean absolute difference of the two numerical vectors is computed. If this is smaller than tolerance or not finite, *absolute differences* are used, otherwise *relative differences scaled by the mean absolute target value*. (Note that these comparisons are computed only for those vector elements where target is not NA and differs from current.)

So, reversing target and current arguments, we get

```
all.equal(target=2, current=25, tolerance=5) 
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 23"
```

which is what we might have expected.

Note that we could also get this by setting the scale argument to 1:

```
all.equal(target=25, current=2, tolerance=5, scale=1) 
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 23"
```

or only naming scale,

```
all.equal(25, 2, 5, scale=1) 
[1] "Mean absolute difference: 23"
```

which re-affirms the comments in the OP.